# GCC: Specified bound depends on the length of the source argument

Tags: c++, gcc

The following code:

```
while (node)
{
    if (node->previous== NULL) break;
    struct Node* prevNode = node->previous;
    len = strlen(prevNode->entity);
    //pp is a char* fyi
    pp-=len;
    strncpy(pp, prevNode->entity, len+1);
    *(--pp) = '/';
    node = prevNode;
}
```

Generates the following warning/error in GCC (I treat all warnings as errors):

```
../someFile.C:1116:24: error: 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
 1116 |                 strncpy(pp, prevNode->entity, len+1);
      |                 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../someFile.C:1114:29: note: length computed here
 1114 |                 len = strlen(prevNode->entity);
      |                       ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is GCC giving me a warning? What is wrong with relieing on the size of a source argument for the buffer size? Can someone give an example of what issues this may cause? Code does what it should I'm just curious why I'm getting a warning.

Comment: As described in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), the 3rd argument of `strncpy` means "maximum number of characters to copy", as in, the maximum size, that can fit inside the `pp` buffer. In your case, it doesn't, necessarily, mean that, hence the diagnostic (technically, such invocation would function identically to `strcpy`). Without [mcve] one cannot provide detailed answer, as it is unclear how `pp` is allocated.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `strncpy` at all here, unless it's some brainless project requirement imposed on you from above. `len=strlen(src); strncpy(dest,src,len+1);` is equivalent to `strcpy (dest.src);`, except that `strncpy` pads with nulls.

Comment: @TonyK in this case it's exactly equivalent due to the length given

Comment: @M.M: in this case, yes. But my statement was more general, and I had to add that caveat to preempt the language lawyers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The point is that the length bound passed to `strncpy` should depend on the size of the destination argument, not the source argument. Otherwise, what is it even for? The compiler correctly recognises that there is no point to using `strncpy` here, and gives you an informative error message to that effect.

Comment: for anyone reading this in the future you (depending on your use case) may be able to just switch strcpy to memcpy to kill the compile warning.

Comment: @user3586940: What's wrong with `strcpy`, for goodness' sake?

Comment: If you know the size of the buffer in advance, memcpy would be faster. If you didn't know the size of the buffer, then this error would never happen. Hence in this case, I think memcpy is the better solution to this compiler warning.

Comment: I got this warning when using this code:char result[260];
int len;
char block[260];
[..]
len=strlen(result);
if(len>255) len=255;
block[0]=nr;
strncpy(&block[1],result,len);

Comment: Sorry, got telephone while editing. What I wanted to say is: In my code I got the same warning but I checked the value of len and adjusted it if it is to big. The null terminator is not important for me.

Comment: Oke, found it myself. In my case I should use memcpy.

Answer (score 2):

According the man page,

"The stpncpy() and strncpy() functions copy at most len characters from src into dst.  If src is less than len characters long, the remainder of dst is filled with `\0' characters.  Otherwise, dst is not terminated."

This has nothing to do with the amount of space in the destination buffer, but rather the number of characters needed to be copied.  If one wishes to copy len characters from src into dst and src has more than len characters, then substituting strcpy will not produce the same results.  Also, if the dst buffer's size was allocated with the expected size, then strcpy will produce a buffer overflow.

In this case the warning is misleading and should be ignored or silenced.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread but couldn't help but point out that the warning is: `-Werror=stringop-overflow=`. This is an indication that you are potentially about to overflow your destination buffer because you are looking to your source buffer to determine how much data to copy.

In the source example:

```c
len = strlen(prevNode->entity);
//pp is a char* fyi
pp-=len;
strncpy(pp, prevNode->entity, len+1);
*(--pp) = '/';
```

We actually have no idea how large the buffer reference by `pp` is at this point. What we do know is the `len` was subtracted from `pp`. By relying on the `strlen(prevNode->entity)` we could attempt to copy 64 bytes into a 32 byte buffer, causing an overflow. What is interesting here is that instead of overflowing the end of the buffer like most buffer overflows, we may actually write into memory space before the actual start of the buffer.

By switching to `memcpy` or `strcpy` all you're doing is ignoring the warning. You're covering up the fact that an overflow is possible. The warning is there for a reason. It means, pay attention, "here be dragons!".